# Interop - put a blank line between pasted tables in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am copying and pasting tables before putting some data in them i(f there is any data for that table).

My problem is I want one blank line between my tables and I can't seem to get it right.

If the table being copied has rows and the new table being copied will have rows, it works fine, but otherwise I either end up with 2 blank lines between tables or the new table is pasted immediately underneath the current table, which is also wrong.

Here is my code:

```
int rowsToGoDown = 2;
if (!firstTable)
{
oWord.Selection.MoveDown(WdUnits.wdLine, rowsToGoDown);
firstTable = true;
}
oWord.Selection.Tables[1].Select();
oWord.Selection.Copy();

if (bNoTransactions == true)
{
//rowsToGoDown = 3;
oWord.Selection.MoveDown(WdUnits.wdLine, 1);
}
oWord.Selection.MoveDown(WdUnits.wdLine, rowsToGoDown);
oWord.Selection.Paste();
```

surely there is a way to just copy the existing table, out in a blank line before the selection where the new table with be pasted then paste?

I'd appreciate some code help as I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it in the end by outputting a **CRLF** - by using

```
oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph();
```